# Integration on a general equation for instantaneous angular acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, integration, rotational-kinematics, kinematics

An equation for instantaneous angular acceleration is given as:

$$
\alpha \equiv \lim_{\Delta t\to0}\frac{\Delta \omega}{\Delta t} = \frac{d\omega}{dt}
$$

The text I am reading says writing this equation in differential form

$$
dw = \alpha dt
$$

and integrating from $t_1$ = 0 to $t_f$ = $t$ gives

$$
\omega_f = \omega_i + \alpha t
$$

I am not exactly sure how the authors came to this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To be even more specific I understand the $\alpha t$ term, but I cannot figure out where the $\omega_f$ & $\omega_i$ came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with
\begin{align}
  \alpha(t) = \frac{d\omega}{dt}(t).
\end{align}
Integrate both sides from $t_i$ to $t_f$;
\begin{align}
  \int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt\,\alpha(t) = \int_{t_i}^{t_f}dt\, \frac{d\omega}{dt}(t) = \omega(t_f) - \omega (t_i)
\end{align}
The second equality on the right follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus which basically says that if you integrate the derivative of a function, you recover the original function.

Now, *if* $\alpha(t)$ is constant in time, namely it has no dependence on $t$, then it can be pulled outside of the integral on the left, and we obtain
\begin{align}
  \alpha\cdot(t_f-t_i) = \omega(t_f) -\omega(t_i) 
\end{align}
Which is the desired identity.

Comment: @ao2130 Sure thing.  Welcome to physics.SE.